# Kubernetes certificate validation

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a Kubernetes cluster with Neo4j installed with helm. I need a certificate but I have many constraints to generate and validate the certificate.

What i have tried:

- Use Kubernetes Cert-manager

  - With http01 validation: not possible because neo4j-helm is creating a load balancer without automatic http01 validation
  - With dns01 validation: not possible because I can't have access to the DNS zone. I can only send a ticket with the new DNS records to create.
- Use certbot

  - With httHTTP validation: not possible for the same reason as above
  - With DNS validation: not possible because it requires interactions

The whole process needs to be automated without user interaction. For instance, we can use CronJob.